# How do I use the datetime module in IronPython?

Tags: .net, python, datetime, ironpython

I am trying to port a program of mine from running on the CPython interpreter to IronPython. The latest part that stumps me is where I use the datetime class from the datetime module.  Here is what happens when I try to use the strptime function.

```
» from datetime import datetime
» dt = datetime.strptime("21/11/06 16:30", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'type' object has no attribute 'strptime'
»
```

Is there something I need to be aware of that makes datetime specially different in IronPython?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For no particular reason, `datetime.strptime` was missing until IronPython 2.7.1. If you're stuck on an older version, you can use `time.strptime` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but how recent is that release? I just did a fresh install from codeplex site about a week ago and it had this problem.

Comment: October 21st. If sys.version is 2.7.1 (or it says 'IronPython 2.7.1 ...' when you start ipy.exe then you've got the latest one.

Comment: Wow, I think I downloaded it the day right before that. Thanks!